# Why is $0$ not an eigenvalue?

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, boundary-value-problem

> I have the following Sturm-Liouville problem 
>   \begin{cases}
> u''+\lambda u =0 & 0 < x < 1, \\ u(0)-u'(0)=0, & u(1)+u'(1)=0,
> \end{cases}
>   and I am trying to show that all the eigenvalues $\lambda$ are positive.

I multiplied both sides by $u$, integrated with respect to $x$ from $0$ to $1$, applied initial conditions, and algebraically rearranged the result to obtain $$\lambda \int_0^1 u^2 \, dx = \int_0^1 (u')^2 \, dx + u(1)^2+u(0)^2.$$
This tells that $\lambda$ is nonnegative, or $\lambda \ge 0$. But I need to also show that $\lambda$ is positive, or $\lambda > 0$. To do this, I must show that $0$ cannot be an eigenvalue, or $\lambda \not=0$. But how can I show this? I'm aware this may be trivial, but I do not see it.

Comment: @vadim123 The definition of eigenvalue excludes the trivial solution $u = 0$.

Comment: @Robert Israel: Eigenvectors are required to be non-zero, but eigenvalues aren't.

Comment: @RobArthan Yes, that's exactly what I meant (this was in response to vadim123's earlier comment, which is now deleted).

Comment: @Robert Israel: That makes sense. Without the deleted comment, I didn't know that you meant "excludes the trivial case where the (putative) eigenvector is zero".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you plug $\lambda = 0$ into your ODE, you get that $u'' = 0$, i.e. $u(x) = ax+b$ for some $a,b$. Using your initial conditions you get that:

$$u(0) - u'(0) = 0 \Longrightarrow b-a = 0$$

and

$$u(1) + u'(1) = 0 \Longrightarrow 2a+b = 0$$

The only solution to these two is if $a=0=b$, i.e. $u\equiv 0$. This is the trivial solution which is why we ignore it. $0$ is always a solution to a homogeneous ODE.

Comment: ...or note that if $\lambda=0$ then $u(1)^2+u(0)^2=0$.

Comment: @vadim123 Good point!

Comment: @CameronWilliams What if now you have the problem $$u''+(\lambda - x^2)u = 0$$ with $u'(0)=u(1)=0$? As usual I was able to prove $\lambda \ge 0$. But how do I show $\lambda$ is positive? When I substitute $\lambda=0$ into the problem, I get $u''-x^2u=0$, a second-order, linear, variable-coefficient ODE whose solution is probably represented as a power series. I am unable to follow a method similar to yours for this equation.

Comment: @CameronWilliams Unless one should actually find such a power series, then implement the initial conditions, so that one can still find only the trivial solution $u\equiv 0$.

Comment: @dragon Definitely try to come up with a solution via power series then use the initial conditions to figure out what the coefficients have to be. You should get two recursion relations: one for the even terms and one for the odd.

Comment: @CameronWilliams I know the solution can be obtained by hand, but I did it on Maple instead, and it indeed confirmed the trivial solution. (http://i.stack.imgur.com/KbP5A.png) My teacher said the scope of our work should mostly be PDEs (I'm in a graduate-level applied PDE class right now), and computational software can be used to bypass ODE work. That, and some of us may have had nightmares with series solutions in our first class in ODEs and would prefer not to solve the ODE manually again at this time. :)

Comment: Haha that's understandable! Glad it worked out :)